# Trying to Minimize Repetitive code in Zip-to-Barcode program

Tags: c++

First time posting here so if I'm doing something wrong let me know...new to the whole programming thing.

So in my class we are doing the zip to bar code converter program. I have the program running fine and now I am just trying to cut down on the redundant or repetitive coding. For instance with my function that runs the actual compiling of the zip code to bar code I have 5 switch statements that all run the same exact cases. The only difference is the condition for the switch (digitA, B, C, D, E; the digits of the zip code):

```
// Short Zip Code Converter Function
int zip_to_bar(int digitA, int  digitB, int digitC, int  digitD, int digitE)

{
    int sum;
    string bar_Code = "!", check_Code;
    switch(digitA)
    {
        case 0: bar_Code += "!!..."; break;
        case 1: bar_Code += "...!!"; break;
        case 2: bar_Code += "..!.!"; break;
        case 3: bar_Code += "..!!."; break;
        case 4: bar_Code += ".!..!"; break;
        case 5: bar_Code += ".!.!."; break;
        case 6: bar_Code += ".!!.."; break;
        case 7: bar_Code += "!...!"; break;
        case 8: bar_Code += "!..!."; break;
        case 9: bar_Code += "!.!.."; break;
    }
    switch(digitB)
    {
        case 0: bar_Code += "!!..."; break;
        case 1: bar_Code += "...!!"; break;
        case 2: bar_Code += "..!.!"; break;
        case 3: bar_Code += "..!!."; break;
        case 4: bar_Code += ".!..!"; break;
        case 5: bar_Code += ".!.!."; break;
        case 6: bar_Code += ".!!.."; break;
        case 7: bar_Code += "!...!"; break;
        case 8: bar_Code += "!..!."; break;
        case 9: bar_Code += "!.!.."; break;
    }
    switch(digitC)
    {
        case 0: bar_Code += "!!..."; break;
        case 1: bar_Code += "...!!"; break;
        case 2: bar_Code += "..!.!"; break;
        case 3: bar_Code += "..!!."; break;
        case 4: bar_Code += ".!..!"; break;
        case 5: bar_Code += ".!.!."; break;
        case 6: bar_Code += ".!!.."; break;
        case 7: bar_Code += "!...!"; break;
        case 8: bar_Code += "!..!."; break;
        case 9: bar_Code += "!.!.."; break;
    }
    switch(digitD)
    {
        case 0: bar_Code += "!!..."; break;
        case 1: bar_Code += "...!!"; break;
        case 2: bar_Code += "..!.!"; break;
        case 3: bar_Code += "..!!."; break;
        case 4: bar_Code += ".!..!"; break;
        case 5: bar_Code += ".!.!."; break;
        case 6: bar_Code += ".!!.."; break;
        case 7: bar_Code += "!...!"; break;
        case 8: bar_Code += "!..!."; break;
        case 9: bar_Code += "!.!.."; break;
    }
    switch(digitE)
    {
        case 0: bar_Code += "!!..."; break;
        case 1: bar_Code += "...!!"; break;
        case 2: bar_Code += "..!.!"; break;
        case 3: bar_Code += "..!!."; break;
        case 4: bar_Code += ".!..!"; break;
        case 5: bar_Code += ".!.!."; break;
        case 6: bar_Code += ".!!.."; break;
        case 7: bar_Code += "!...!"; break;
        case 8: bar_Code += "!..!."; break;
        case 9: bar_Code += "!.!.."; break;
    }
    // Sum of Zip_Digits
    sum = (digitA + digitB + digitC + digitD + digitE);
    // Calculation of check_Digit_Code
    check_Code = check_Digit_Code(sum);
    // Assignment of check_Bar_Code to check_Digit_Code
    cout << bar_Code + check_Code << endl;
    return sum;
}
```

I would like to somehow minimize this to where their would be only one switch statement since they are all the same and it would run each digit in a loop. The reason I am wanting to do this is we are having to run short(#####), standard (#####-####), & advanced (#####-####+##) format zip codes. So as you can imagine the program is getting hellishly long and repetitive looking.

I was thinking a for statement loop would work nicely but I'm stuck on what/how to set it up the conditions (what should be initialized when I have 5 variables present in the function?). Obviously what I have got is not going to work how I want but this is what I have so far (any advice on how to handle this problem)?

```
    // Reformatted Version of Short Zip Code Converter Function
    int zip_to_bar_srt(int digitA, int digitB, int digitC, int  digitD, int digitE)
{

    for(int digitA; digitA < 5; digitA++)
    {
        switch(digitA)
        {
            int sum;
            string barCode = "!", check_bar;

            case 0: barCode += "!!..."; break;
            case 1: barCode += "...!!"; break;
            case 2: barCode += "..!.!"; break;
            case 3: barCode += "..!!."; break;
            case 4: barCode += ".!..!"; break;
            case 5: barCode += ".!.!."; break;
            case 6: barCode += ".!!.."; break;
            case 7: barCode += "!...!"; break;
            case 8: barCode += "!..!."; break;
            case 9: barCode += "!.!.."; break;

                sum += digitA;
                check_bar = check(sum);
                cout<<barCode+check_bar<<endl;
                return sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a function that will give you the part of the barcode for a single digit:

```
string get_barcode_part(int digit)
{
    switch(digitA)
    {
        case 0: return "!!...";;
        case 1: return "...!!";;
        case 2: return "..!.!";;
        case 3: return "..!!.";;
        case 4: return ".!..!";;
        case 5: return ".!.!.";;
        case 6: return ".!!..";;
        case 7: return "!...!";;
        case 8: return "!..!.";;
        case 9: return "!.!..";;
        default: return "Invalid"; // or whatever else you want
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call it for each of your digits:

```
// Short Zip Code Converter Function
int zip_to_bar(int digitA, int  digitB, int digitC, int  digitD, int digitE)
{
    int sum;
    string bar_Code = "!", check_Code;

    bar_Code += get_barcode_part(digitA);
    bar_Code += get_barcode_part(digitB);
    bar_Code += get_barcode_part(digitC);
    bar_Code += get_barcode_part(digitD);
    bar_Code += get_barcode_part(digitE);

    // Sum of Zip_Digits
    sum = (digitA + digitB + digitC + digitD + digitE);
    // Calculation of check_Digit_Code
    check_Code = check_Digit_Code(sum);
    // Assignment of check_Bar_Code to check_Digit_Code
    cout << bar_Code + check_Code << endl;
    return sum;
}
```

This is the essential function of functions (heh): to refactor and reduce copied code, by putting common functionality in a common place.

**Edit:** In addition, you should probably use an array for your digits, like so:

```
// Short Zip Code Converter Function
int zip_to_bar(int *digits, int numDigits)
{
    int sum = 0;
    string bar_Code = "!", check_Code;

    for (int i = 0; i < numDigits; i++)
    {
        bar_Code += get_barcode_part(digits[i]);
        // Sum of Zip_Digits
        sum += digits[i];
    }

    // Calculation of check_Digit_Code
    check_Code = check_Digit_Code(sum);
    // Assignment of check_Bar_Code to check_Digit_Code
    cout << bar_Code + check_Code << endl;
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is with a table

```
string bar_Codes[] = {"!!...",  "...!!", ...};
```

and then

```
bar_Code += bar_Codes[digitA];
bar_Code += bar_Codes[digitB];
bar_Code += bar_Codes[digitC];
```

Less efficient, but equally easy is make a function:

```
void getBarCode(int digit, string & bar_Code)
{
    switch(digit)
    {
        case 0: bar_Code += "!!..."; break;
        case 1: bar_Code += "...!!"; break;
        case 2: bar_Code += "..!.!"; break;
        ....
    }
}
```

and then

```
getBarCode(digitA, bar_Code);
getBarCode(digitB, bar_Code);
getBarCode(digitC, bar_Code);
...
```

All you need to do is ensure the digit is in the allowable range